# Why jQuery scroll top not working with animate?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make my website's scroll to top with animate.
I make a script for this , I am using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#scrollToTop').click(function(){
     $( 'html, body' ).animate( { scrollTop: 0 }, 0 );
   });
});
```

but it's not working.
please solve this

Comment: Your code works. http://jsfiddle.net/1xae19oh/

Comment: You have your animation duration set to zero so it happens instantaniously

Comment: Yup, if you just took a peak in the jquery docs, you'd see that the 0 in the end stands for duration of the animation.